# Form fields not saved to database in RoR standard MVC CRUD operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails 4.1.0

My view:

```
<%= form_for @book do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :author %>
    <%= f.number_field :pages %>
    <%= f.text_field :description %>
    <%= f.submit "Add book" %>
<% end %>
```

My controller:

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @book = Book.new
  end
  def create
    @book = Book.new(book_params)
    if @book.save
        redirect_to '/', notice: "You have succesfully added a book"
    else
        flash.now[:error] = "Something went wrong"
        render :new
    end
  end

  private
  def book_params
    params.require(:book).permit(:title, :author, :pages, :description)
  end
end
```

And my model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    validates :title, presence: true
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

    attr_accessor :title, :author, :pages, :description
end
```

Basic CRUD, but when I try to save to the DB, only an empty record is created, which is reflected in the development logs:

```
Started POST "/books" for 10.0.2.2 at 2014-05-05 22:59:08 +0000
Processing by BooksController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SDB/oB/CjZsBHmI0zLPmQnKpZSxO7piGnsLSzEy2hyA=", "book"=>{"title"=>"tittel", "author"=>"te", "pages"=>"", "description"=>""}, "commit"=>"Add book"}
  [1m[36m (0.2ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mBook Exists (3.9ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "books"  WHERE "books"."title" = 'tittel' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (5.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "books" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", "2014-05-05 22:59:08.989197"], ["updated_at", "2014-05-05 22:59:08.989197"]]
  [1m[35m (5.9ms)[0m  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3003/
Completed 302 Found in 26ms (ActiveRecord: 15.0ms)
```

What am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're mixing up two overlapping concepts here:

The old(ish) way to allow only certain params to create DB records is to whitelist them, which I think is what you were attempting with the `attr_accessor`, except the correct method is `attr_accessible`.

The new way to contorl which params can create DB records is the [strong params](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/) pattern, which you've implemented with the private `book_params` method. But you don't need to do the whitelisting if you're doing the strong params bit.

So if you just take out the `attr_accessor` bit altogether, that should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, this was indeed the issue!